# Frontend External Image Compression

Tags: javascript, html, compression

I'm displaying images from the National Parks Service API for a web app and the images displaying in the thumbnails are causing a lot of lag.

Is there a way to compress image urls before displaying or reduce the lag somehow?

The code below is how the images are displayed.

```
for (let j = 0; j < parkInfo.data[i].images.length; j++) {
  $('#pics').append('<img src="' + parkInfo.data[i].images[j].url +
    '" width="33%" altText="' + parkInfo.data[i].images[j].altText +
    '" class="img-thumbnail">');
```

Example image:
[image]

How the images are displayed currently:
[image]

Comment: If you have a backend service, you can run your images through a proxy which handles compression/resize as needed. To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do this purely on the browser (unless you use another third party service - there are many)

Comment: _Is there a way to compress image urls before displaying or reduce the lag somehow?_ - No, but you can precache them.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287750/how-do-i-pre-cache-images-for-quick-viewing-with-javascript