# Preloading Image to Precache

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to preload my images but don't necessarily want to append them to the DOM. If I preload an image will it effectively be precached?

My understanding is that caching works by reference to the `src` of an image. From playing around it seems as if preloading in order to precache does indeed work. However, I'm not sure; this may be unreliable or have some negative effect on performance.

I'm using the image constructor to preload.

```
const img = new Image();
img.src = imageArray[i].url;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287750/how-do-i-pre-cache-images-for-quick-viewing-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does indeed work.

```
function preloadImage(url){
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imageArray[i].url;
}
```

However, there is a couple of approach. For example, delaying preloading until after the page loads:

```js
function preloader() {
    if (document.images) {
        var img1 = new Image();
        var img2 = new Image();
        var img3 = new Image();

        img1.src = "http://url/image-001.jpg";
        img2.src = "http://url/image-002.jpg";
        img3.src = "http://url/image-003.jpg";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
```